# How to mount a volume in Docker for windows?

Tags: python, windows, docker

I'm trying to save data from my docker app to a host folder.
My dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3
   
# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8050

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

I then build the image:

```
docker build <path> -t <tag>
```

And then run:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 <tag>
```

In order to save the output from the docker app, which I was trying to do like this

```
pd.DataFrame(rows).to_excel('S:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/file.xlsx', index=False)
```

I have to mount the volume, within Docker Settings>Resources>File Sharing I've added the directory 'S:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/' so that it can be mounted into Docker containers.

And then I tried to run the image:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 -v "s:/folder1/folder2/folder3/":"/data" <tag>
```

this pop ups a window "Docker wants to access to C\dc\Shared\folder1\folder2\folder3" And I can choose to share or cancel, after selecting share, folder 3 is created in the right location but I get the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/uC/dc/Shared/folder1/folder2/folder3/': mkdir /host_mnt/uC: operation not permitted.
```

If I try a location on my C: drive this works without problems, it's just the shared drive that is giving me problems.

What is the right way to mount the volume so I can then save to that folder? Thank you

Comment: Do you call pd.DataFrame(rows).to_excel from inside docker? If so you do wrong. You have to call /data/file.xls instead.

Comment: I just tested with my windows. Shared directory in docker settings:
```C:\Development\temp```
Built image there with your commands. 
Started it's shell with 
```docker run -it -p 8050:8050 -v "C:\Development\temp":"/data" test bash```
Then I was able to write new file 
```echo "Testing" > /data/testing``` to mounted directory.
So does your Python code.

Comment: @GintsGints yes I call it from inside docker - I'm not sure what you mean by call /data/file.xls instead though

Comment: You cannot use windows path inside docker container. Use linux path instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your containerized app should call /data folder instead.

Comment: Thanks! But I think the error occurs before saving, docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/uC/dc/Shared/folder1/folder2/folder3/': mkdir /host_mnt/uC: operation not permitted.

Comment: Try repeat my test.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: Can you execute your container bash, and create file when inside container?

Comment: Do you mean execute this? docker run -p 8050:8050 -v "s:/folder1/folder2/folder3/":"/data" <tag>